# Apache Ignite - error 'JavaLoggerFileHandler' when running Spark shell

Tags: java, apache-spark, ignite

I am starting spark-shell (of spark 2.2) and added bunch of jars in spark-shell command (from Ignite 2.1 directory).

Still getting error:

```
Can't load log handler "org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler"
```

Also followed recommendation from here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.2/docs/installation--deployment

```
# Optionally set IGNITE_HOME here.
# IGNITE_HOME=/path/to/ignite

IGNITE_LIBS="${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/*"

for file in ${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/*
do
    if [ -d ${file} ] && [ "${file}" != "${IGNITE_HOME}"/libs/optional ]; then
        IGNITE_LIBS=${IGNITE_LIBS}:${file}/*
    fi
done

export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$IGNITE_LIBS
```

Also set logging to only ERROR as well but still getting error:

```
Can't load log handler "org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use documentation for an old Ignite version 1.2, while you use Ignite 2.1. Check the documentation for the latest version here: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.2/docs/installation-deployment

Also, please make sure that have configured IGNITE_HOME in your environment. JavaLoggerFileHandler placed in the ignite-core module, looks like spark classpath doesn't see any Ignite lib at all.

Comment: Followed instructions from (https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.2/docs/installation-deployment) and made sure IGNITE_HOME is set before starting Spark shell and also added all the jars with  command 'spark-shell --jars ..ignite-core-2.1.0.jar..' but still have the same issue: `Can't load log handler "org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) 
 `

Comment: I can connect to Ignite from Spark shell by the way - but these errors above are showing up...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describe the issue here:

https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.2/docs/troubleshooting

> This issue appears when you do not have any loggers included in classpath and Ignite tries to use standard Java logging. By default Spark loads all user jar files using separate class loader. Java logging framework, on the other hand, uses application class loader to initialize log handlers. To resolve this, you can either add ignite-log4j module to the list of the used jars so that Ignite would use Log4j as a logging subsystem, or alter default Spark classpath as described